# Kivy : Widget.on_touch_down button

Tags: kivy

In Mark Vasilkov - "Kivy Blueprints" Chapter 2 Paint App, touch between Widget and Button is differentiated by following code (captured within *** block. I dont know how to bold it or change the color of the line). I tried understanding from the  document but unable to grasp the context. Please help me how Widget.on_touch_down just return when Button is touched and circle is drawn if not touched on Button

```
# In paint.kv
<CanvasWidget>:
  Button:
    text: 'Delete'
    right: root.right
    top: root.top
    width: 80
    height: 40
    on_release: root.clear_canvas()

# In main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ***if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch): #How this check identify that the touch is on button***
           return

        with self.canvas:
            Color(*get_color_from_hex('#0080FF80'))
            Line(circle=(touch.x, touch.y, 25), width=4)

    def clear_canvas(self):
        saved = self.children[:]  # See below
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.canvas.clear()
        for widget in saved:
            self.add_widget(widget)

class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CanvasWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '540')
    Config.set('input', 'mouse',
               'mouse,disable_multitouch')

    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#FFFFFF')

    PaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty old book. I think the recommended way to do that now is to replace:

```
if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
```

with:

```
if super(CanvasWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch):
```

Both have the same effect. The call to the super class `on_touch_down()` lets the `Event` (the `touch`) bubble through its normal dispatching. If the `touch` is on the `Button`, then the `on_touch_down()` method of the `Button` will return `True`, which means that the `Button` has claimed the `Event`, and no other `Widgets` should process it. A `False` return means that the `on_touch_down()` of the `Button` determined that the `touch` was not on the `Button` and dispatching should continue.

Comment: Thanks. But here I do not have separate on_touch_down for button and Canvaswidget. But I do have on_release event trigger for the button. So where is the "return True" happens for Button.

Comment: The `Button` has its own `on_touch_down()` written by the developers.